# How to use rvest in order to get dynamic data from Lux to Lumens Calculator

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler, rvest

The [Lux to Lumens Calculator](https://www.bannerengineering.com/za/en/company/expert-insights/lux-lumens-calculator.html#) provides relationship between Lux, Lumens, LED Beam Angle and Distance from Surface to Light. Lux and Lumens have input fields while LED Beam Angle and Distance from Surface to Light have sliding bar to set the desired values.

I appreciate if someone can help me and explain (possibly step by step) how to use rvest to obtain either Lux or Lumen values given specified LED Beam Angle and Distance from Surface to Light values. I used rvest to crawl static data from webpages, but lack any experience doing it on webpages with dynamic input through specific form submission.

I used the following code to extract the form from the webpage but it seems this is not correct attempt:

```
library (rvest)

calculator_webpage <- read_html("https://www.bannerengineering.com/za/en/company/expert-insights/lux-lumens-calculator.html#")

calculator_webpage %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()
```

Comment: I think `rvest` alone will struggle here since there is no form submission - results are generated dynamically using Javascript when data is entered. You may need to use RSelenium, or you may be able to run the underlying Javascript in R using the V8 package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation is done client side in Javascript, specifically [with these JS functions](https://www.bannerengineering.com/apps/designs/banner/clientlibs/luxlumencalci.js), (note the `calculateLumens` and `calculateLux` functions). This is why you don't see anything in the html itself (using rvest).

The code can be easily transposed in R like the following :

```
convertDegreesToRadians <- function(angleInDegrees) {
   return(angleInDegrees * pi / 180)
}

calculateLux <- function(lumens, surfaceAreaToIlluminate, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees) {
    modifier <- calculateLuxLumensModifier(surfaceAreaToIlluminate, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees)
    return(lumens / modifier)
}

calculateLuxLumensModifier <- function(surfaceAreaToIlluminate, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees) {
    beamAngleInRadians <- convertDegreesToRadians(beamAngleInDegrees)
    modifier <- surfaceAreaToIlluminate * distanceFromSurfaceToLight^2 * 2 * pi * (1 - cos(beamAngleInRadians / 2))
    return(modifier)
}

calculateLumens <- function(lux, surfaceAreaToIlluminate, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees) {
    modifier = calculateLuxLumensModifier(surfaceAreaToIlluminate, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees)
    return(lux * modifier)
}

getLuxFromLumens <- function(lumens, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees){
    calLux <- calculateLux(lumens,1,distanceFromSurfaceToLight,beamAngleInDegrees)
    return(round(calLux))
}

getLumensFromLux <- function(lux,distanceFromSurfaceToLight,beamAngleInDegrees){
    calLumen <- calculateLumens(lux,1,distanceFromSurfaceToLight,beamAngleInDegrees)
    return(round(calLumen))
}

calculateBeamWidth <- function(distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees) {
    beamAngleInRadians <- convertDegreesToRadians(beamAngleInDegrees)
    return(round(2 * distanceFromSurfaceToLight * tan(beamAngleInRadians / 2), digits=2))
}

# get lux from lumens, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees
print(getLuxFromLumens(lumens = 1000, distanceFromSurfaceToLight= 0.1, beamAngleInDegrees=120))

# get luments from lux, distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees
print(getLumensFromLux(lux = 1000, distanceFromSurfaceToLight= 0.1, beamAngleInDegrees=120))

# get beam width from distanceFromSurfaceToLight, beamAngleInDegrees
print(calculateBeamWidth(distanceFromSurfaceToLight = 0.1,beamAngleInDegrees = 120))
```

[Run this example on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/CalculateLuxLumen)

Comment: Before posting on SO, I tried to inspect elements "Lux" and "Lumens" in Chrome and both are within the element '<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/designs/banner/clientlibs/luxlumencalci.js"></script>' which is actually JS function as you point out. Unfortunately, I didn't know to open it to see the code. Lol. I missed to add the prefix (main URL - 'https://www.bannerengineering.com'). Tnx a lot!